# Function problem I always get the first refund

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to make a function that will tell me if all the members of the list are even, I defined the function and tried to use a loop that will go through each member of the list each time and tell me if it is even or not, the function does not match what I try and it always returns the first return.
This is the code I tried:

```
def all_even(lst):
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(lst))` doesn't loop over the items in a list.

Comment: `return not any( 1 for i in lst if i%2==1)`

Comment: @EricÁvila That's fine here.  If any of the values are "odd", then they are not `all_even` and it's ok to exit the function.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Or `all(i%2 == 0 for i in lst)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def all_even(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing index number not the value on that index in the list. `range` provide a generator which start from 0 index to `len(list)` index (last index exclusive) ie `[0,1,2,3...n)`

in your code you are checking the odd condition on index only not on the element. that is why you are getting the output

Below code is what you are trying to achieve

```
def all_even(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]%2 != 0: # accessing and checkingvalue on the ith index in list lst
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Or just `for i in lst`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yeah that also works. either directly access the element value or by index. both work fine.